# sqlalchemy, alembic with postgres and postgis drop tables in other schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm working with Alembic with SQLAlchemy and I'm a newbie with Python.
Database: postgres with with postgis (with tiger schema and others)

I created a class into models.py file that define my tables.

```
class Adv(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'advs'
  __table_args__ = {"schema": "screech"}
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = Column(String)
  description = Column(String)
  ...
```

if I run
`alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Create table advs"`, in the generated file I can see many rows like that
`op.drop_table('place', schema='tiger')` that refer to all tables in the other schemas.

How can I avoid this behavior? I just want to add a table

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Comment: @P4nd4b0b3r1n0 no, I didn't but actually I didn't try so much. At the end I had the chance to use a mysql database. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

In env.py you can configure which schemas/tables/columns you want to be auto generated and which not with include_name and include_object functions.
Link to documentation https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#autogenerate-include-hooks

I just filter all the tables that are not present in target_metadata:

```
def include_name(name, type_, parent_names):
    if type_ == "table":
        return name in target_metadata.tables
    return True
...
context.configure(
    # ...
    include_name=include_name
)
```